# Google Apps Scripts - Add Timestamp to multiple cells when updated

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to update the code in [this tutorial](https://www.internetgeeks.org/tech/add-timestamp-time-stamp-google-docs-spreadsheet/) to add a timestamp when I update a cell.  So far it's working for the first cell but not all of them when copying values to a whole range.

Could someone take a look and help adapt this so that all cells are updated with a timestamp rather than just the first?

Thanks!

```html
function onEdit(event)
{ 
  var timezone = "GMT+1";
  var timestamp_format = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"; // Timestamp Format. 
  var updateColName = "Message";
  var timeStampColName = "Timestamp";
  var sheet = event.source.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); //Name of the sheet where you want to run this script.


  var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
  var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(timeStampColName);
  var updateCol = headers[0].indexOf(updateColName); updateCol = updateCol+1;
  if (dateCol > -1 && index > 1 && editColumn == updateCol) { // only timestamp if 'Last Updated' header exists, but not in the header row itself!
    var cell = sheet.getRange(index, dateCol + 1);
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format);
    cell.setValue(date);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using [getRange(row, column)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column) which retrieves a single cell.

The following lines are setting only first cell's value in the range when you copy paste multiple values or pull down a cell:

> var cell = sheet.getRange(index, dateCol + 1);

> cell.setValue(date);

Use [getRange(row, column, numRows)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer)) to retrieve a range with multiple rows. If we change it with:

> sheet.getRange (index, dateCol + 1, numRows)

it will change all cells in this range.

Try this please.

```
function onEdit(event) { 
  var timezone = "GMT+1";
  var timestamp_format = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"; // Timestamp Format. 
  var updateColName = "Message";
  var timeStampColName = "Timestamp";
  var sheet = event.source.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); //Name of the sheet where you want to run this script.    
  var actRng = event.range;
  var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
  var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
  var numRows = actRng.getNumRows();
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(timeStampColName);
  var updateCol = headers[0].indexOf(updateColName)+1; 
  if (dateCol > -1 && index > 1 && editColumn == updateCol) { 
    var range = sheet.getRange(index, dateCol + 1,numRows);
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format);
    range.setValue(date);
  }
}
```

#### Reference:

- [getRange(row, column)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column)
- [getRange(row, column, numRows)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer))

Comment: Hey Muhammet, thanks but I'm actually trying to get the script updated so that it adds a timestamp to all the updated rows when you're copying a value into multiple cells or pulling down a formula.  At the moment it only adds one to the top cell.